# How can I use the EXECUTE command for this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, exec, execute

We have a SQL Server 2014, with about 20+ Linked (oracle) Servers.
From time-to-time, I need to check the USER ID (on the Oracle side) status for all of these linked servers.

I currently use the following OPENQUERY statement for this:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY (MYLINKEDORACLESERVER,'SELECT * FROM SYS.USER_USERS')
```

Outputs:

[image]

However, because of the amount of servers, we're looking for a more automated way of doing this.

SYS.SERVERS outputs a list of all linked oracle servers (I've added the OPENQUERY syntax)

```
SELECT 'select * from openquery ('+ name +',''SELECT * FROM USER_USERS'')' FROM sys.servers 
WHERE provider='OraOLEDB.Oracle'
```

Outputs:

[image]

How can I leverage the EXECUTE statement so that it automatically EXECUTES each OPENQUERY statement that it outputs?

Desired output:

[image]

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method would be to string aggregate them, and then execute them all in a single batch. As you're not in SQL Server 2017+, you'll be to use the old `FOR XML PATH` method:

```sql
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SET @SQL =  STUFF((SELECT @CRLF + N'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY('+ QUOTENAME(s.[name]) + ',''SELECT * FROM USER_USERS'');'
                   FROM sys.servers 
                   FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,2,N'');

PRINT @SQL; --Your best friend
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```